# Strong data-processing inequality: bound $TV(T_{\#}P_0,T_{\#}P_1)$ if $\|T(x)-x\|_\infty \le \varepsilon;\forall x \in \mathbb R^p$

Tags: pr.probability, it.information-theory, st.statistics, upper-bounds

**Disclaimer.** I've moved this question from MO hoping that here is the right venue. Also, this is my first post on this channel, so please have some patience.

So, Iet $X = (X,d)$ be a Polish space, equipped with the Borel sigma-algebra and $P_0,P_1$ be probability distributions on $X$. Let $\mathcal M(X,X)$ be the measurable maps $X\rightarrow X$, and for each $T \in \mathcal M(X,X)$, let the measure $T_{\#}P_k$ be the *push-forward* of $P_k$ by $T$.  For $\varepsilon \ge 0$, let $\mathcal T_\varepsilon$ be the set of all $T \in \mathcal M(X,X)$ such that $\sup_{x \in X}d(T(x),x) \le \varepsilon$. Define $\alpha_\varepsilon$ via the optimization problem

$$
\alpha_\varepsilon := \min_{T \in \mathcal T_\varepsilon} TV(T_{\#}P_0, T_{\#}P_1).
$$

Note that by the *data-processing inequality*, it holds that
$$
0 \le \alpha_\varepsilon \le TV(P_0,P_1) \le 1.
$$
Unfortunately, this bound is presumably very loose as it is independent of the parameter $\varepsilon$.

## Question

- Is there a nontrivial upper bound on $\alpha_\varepsilon$ in terms of $P_0$, $P_1$ and $\varepsilon$ ? My wild guess (and hope!) is something of the form 
  "$\alpha_\varepsilon \le g(\varepsilon)TV(P_0,P_1)$",
  where $g_\varepsilon:[0,1]\rightarrow [0, 1]$ is a nontrivial function such that $g_\varepsilon(t) < t$ for $t \in (0, 1)$.
- Same question for the special case $X=(\mathbb R^p,\|\cdot-\cdot\|_\infty)$. Note that in this case, $\alpha_\varepsilon$ can be written as
  $$
  \alpha_\varepsilon := \inf_{T_1,\ldots,T_p \in \mathcal M(\mathbb R^p,\mathbb R) \text{ s.t } x_j - \varepsilon \le T_j(x) \le x_j + \varepsilon\;\forall j \in [\![p]\!]} TV(T_{\#}P_0,T_{\#}P_1)
  $$
- Same question for the Hamming cube $X = (\{0, 1\}^p, d_{\text{H}})$. In this case, we can rewrite
  $$
  \alpha_\varepsilon = \inf_{T:\{0, 1\}^p \rightarrow \{0, 1\} \text{ s.t } \sum_{j \mid T(x)_j \ne j} 1 \le \varepsilon,\;\forall x \in \{0, 1\}^p} TV(T_{\#}P_0,T_{\#}P_1)
  $$

Comment: I've asked an extended / generalized version of the question here https://mathoverflow.net/q/349136/78539.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but what about $P_0$ and $P_1$ being on disjoint subsets (say, even elements) at distance $\gg \varepsilon$? The TV is one, and for any admissible $T$, the distance between $TP_0$ and $TP_1$ is still one (supports still disjoint).

Comment: As you rightly point-out, in case $P_0$ and $P_1$ have disjoint supports separated by a distance $r > 0$, then if $r < \varepsilon$, we have $T(T_{\#}P_0,T_{\#}P_1) = 1$ for all admissible $T$ indeed. This is not an issue, as even in this case, it's interesting to understand what happens when $r \le \varepsilon$. To avoid such issues (?), you may restrict to scenarios where $P_0 \ll P_1 \ll P_0$.

Comment: I see. You may still have similar issues when $P_0\ll P_1\ll P_0$, though (so I don't think this assumption makes much difference): e.g., take two distributions supported on the integers, $\mathbb{N}$. For $\varepsilon < 1/2$, any admissible $T$ will preserve the total variation distance.

Comment: Sure, those are some nice pathological cases I didn't think of. Under the hood, I'm only interested in nice cases (e.g when $P_0$ and $P_1$ have density w.r.t to some well-behaved reference measure, e.g Lebesgue, when the space allows). For example, as stated in the question results on the space $(X,\|\cdot-\cdot\|_p)$ for $p \in [1,\infty]$ will already be nice to have.

Comment: As a maybe instructive way to start, do you have a nontrivial bound for $P_0$ the standard Gaussian (and $P_1$ an arbitrary Gaussian) in one dimension?

Comment: Yes, if $P_k = \mathcal N(\mu_k,\sigma^2)$, then quick (and dirty) calculation should give $\alpha_\varepsilon = 2 \Phi(\sigma^{-1}\max(|\mu_0-\mu_1|-\varepsilon, 0))-1$ (exact formula !). Using Pinker's inequality, a similar argument would give good upper bounds for general exponential families.